# Can't install kgio 2.8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, bundler

**Note:** I'm running Ubuntu, not Windows.

This is what happens when trying to install kgio. Am I missing dependencies, what do I install?

```
gilani@debris$ gem install kgio -v '2.8.1' 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing kgio:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/gilani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151218-13133-1dvzrlz.rb extconf.rb
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... yes
checking for clockid_t in time.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime() in -lrt... yes
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for poll() in poll.h... yes
checking for getaddrinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... yes
checking for getnameinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_storage in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h... yes
checking for accept4() in sys/socket.h... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_io_t.fd in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_io_t.mode in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_io_t.pathv in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
checking for struct RFile in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
checking size of struct RFile in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... 24
checking for struct RObject... yes
checking size of struct RObject... 40
checking size of int... 4
checking for rb_io_ascii8bit_binmode()... yes
checking for rb_update_max_fd()... yes
checking for rb_fd_fix_cloexec()... yes
checking for rb_cloexec_open()... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_io_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes
checking for rb_time_interval()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_str_subseq()... yes
checking for rb_ary_subseq()... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling wait.c
compiling autopush.c
compiling tryopen.c
tryopen.c:42:0: warning: "RUBY_UBF_IO" redefined [enabled by default]
 #  define RUBY_UBF_IO ((void *)(-1))
 ^
In file included from /home/gilani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1710:0,
                 from /home/gilani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from tryopen.c:1:
/home/gilani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:902:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define RUBY_UBF_IO ((rb_unblock_function_t *)-1)
 ^
In file included from tryopen.c:43:0:
/home/gilani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/rubysig.h:14:2: warning: #warning rubysig.h is obsolete [-Wcpp]
 #warning rubysig.h is obsolete
  ^
tryopen.c: In function ‘my_thread_blocking_region’:
tryopen.c:52:2: error: ‘TRAP_BEG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  TRAP_BEG; /* for FIFO */
  ^
tryopen.c:52:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
tryopen.c:54:2: error: ‘TRAP_END’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  TRAP_END;
  ^
make: *** [tryopen.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/gilani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/kgio-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/gilani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/kgio-2.8.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Does "/home/gilani/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/kgio-2.8.1/gem_make.out" tell you anything else?

Comment: @theTinMan not at all, it contains the exact error text above, with the exception of the last two statements, ofcourse.

Comment: you are trying to compile the gem against a version of ruby newer than what it was written against, kgio 2.8.1 was released in 2013(http://bogomips.org/kgio.git/tag/?h=v2.8.1), ruby 2.2.1 was released March 2015 (https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/03/03/ruby-2-2-1-released/)

Comment: @bjhaid that fixed it! Thanks! Can you post that as an answer and i'll mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @bjhaid answered in the comments, and didn't follow up. I'll post it here myself to close the questoin:

> you are trying to compile the gem against a version of ruby newer than
>   what it was written against, kgio 2.8.1 was released in
>   2013(bogomips.org/kgio.git/tag/?h=v2.8.1), ruby 2.2.1 was released
>   March 2015 (ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/03/03/ruby-2-2-1-released)

Comment: And I've been banging my head against the wall the past hour trying to get my old rails project to work with ruby `2.3.1`. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of these helped me on Ubuntu 16.04:

`apt-get install ruby-kgio`

`bundle update kgio`

Comment: This didn't help me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Found that if you rvm is not loaded, you might receive same error.
to verify if rvm is loaded try:

```
rvm use 2.x.x
```

if you receive following warning:

> You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login
>   shell. Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the
>   command. Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for
>   an example.

This would probably be also your case :-)

```
/bin/bash --login
rvm use 2.x.x
```

Solved for me after banging head for about an hour+ why could this happens